# NuGet version vs nuget CLI version?

Tags: nuget

I'm currently learning about NuGet, and there is something I just can't figure out: Is the NuGet version (which currently ranges from 1.x to 6.x) is the same as the Nuget.exe version? If not, what is the meaning of the NuGet version, and how do I know which versions of the CLI are compatible with which versions of NuGet?